# Javascript tables paint rows according to value

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

I got the following table (for example, the table is dynamic and may change its values):

```
.negative {
          background-color: red;
          font-weight: bold;
        }
.positive {
          background-color: green;
          font-weight: bold;
        }


<table border="1" align="center" id="testtable1">

<tr>
 <th>#</th>
 <th>Positive</th>
 <th>Negative</th>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="odd">7.4</td>
        <td class="even">4.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td class="odd">1</td>
        <td class="even">5.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class="odd">2</td>
        <td class="even">2.4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and I need to find max values from left and right columns and paint the whole 1 row of each max value to positive (green background) or negative (red) color, so row #1 should be all green, and row #2 should be red. Row #3 should be white (not max values should not be painted). If both positive and negative max values are on the same row, the row should be painted green, and then the second negative max value should be found and painted red. I have got the following JS code so far:

```
function MakeColors() {
 table = document.getElementById("testtable1");
 TRs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
 TDs = document.getElementsByTagName('td')

 var max_val_pos = 0;
 var max_val_neg = 0;
 var max_val_neg2 = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < TDs.length; i++) {

   var temp = TDs[i];
   var tdval = parseFloat(temp.firstChild.nodeValue);
   if(max_val_pos < tdval && temp.className == "odd") {
     max_val_pos = tdval;
   }
   if(max_val_neg < tdval && temp.className == "even") {
     max_val_neg = tdval;
   }
   if(max_val_neg2 < tdval && 
     tdval != max_val_neg && 
     temp.className == "even"){
    max_val_neg2 = tdval;  
  } 
}

for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
 for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++)  {
  if (parseFloat(col.firstChild.nodeValue) == max_val_pos)   {row.className = "positive";}
 if (parseFloat(col.firstChild.nodeValue) == max_val_neg &&    row.className !="positive") {row.className = "negative";}else if(parseFloat(col.firstChild.nodeValue) == max_val_neg2){row.className = "negative";

      }
     }  
   }
 }

MakeColors();
```

The problem is that I cannot find next nearest max value for the negative column if first negative max value changes. Generally speaking, I can find a solution for one case, but when the data changes, the result breaks and I get wrong rows painted. Any ideas how to fix the problem would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Call `makeColors()` again every time you change the data

Comment: Thats actually is the problem. Each time I call makeColors(), it may produce correct or incorrect result depending on the table contents

Comment: Can you describe what the desired outcome should be in this scenario:
https://jsfiddle.net/fgqfqs09/  
Which squares are displaying incorrectly? Are they the wrong colors or the wrong numbers?

Comment: I'm sorry but that explanation was befuddling. You need to clearly define the desired results in the form of a list (on the toolbar; 8th icon from the left ) To simulate the red color use `>` (4th icon), and the code brackets `{}`  (5th icon) for green. When say max value...max value of the row or max value compared to all of the cells in the table?

Comment: As for mike510a fiddle there is a 3rd row green with a positive value of 21.5 which is correct, and there is 2nd row red with the value of 5.4 which is wrong. In that scenario the red row should be the 1st one with the value of 9.4 which is the 2nd negative value after 15.4 in the Negative column. Also you may try the code with different values to see the scenarios where it works and where it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @mike510a you can just call `makeColors()` again every time you change the data, but you have to make some corrections:

1. You need to reset rows which are neither max nor min any more.
2. You need to think about what happens if two values are the same. If there are two max values do you both paint green? If the min and the max are in the same row then you paint the row green, but if there is another row with the same min value then you probably want to paint this row red and not those with the 2nd min found by your algorithm.

So the easiest thing is first to paint the max rows and afterwards the min rows:

1. Find max
2. Paint the max rows and reset the others (`.className = ""`)
3. Find the min, ignoring rows which were already painted
4. Paint the min rows, also ignoring the already painted ones

Comment: So do I need to refactor the code in order to paint the row green after the max is found and then paint the row red only after the max negative is found? Now I have 2 loops - in first one I find max positive and negative (which is the problem if there is no painted rows) and then I paint them.

Comment: Yes you can do 4 loops, each of the points corresponds to a loop. Yes it could be done more efficiently, but I doubt it matters.